# How to route from Istio Gateway HTTPS to HTTP2 Service?

Tags: kubernetes, istio, istio-gateway

I'm trying to receive a request through HTTPS (with TLS termination) and forwarding to a http2 api. Previously my api worked as HTTP 1.1 and now I upgraded his code to work with HTTP2 (plain text).

When I do a curl from another pod inside the cluster, everything works fine with HTTP2.0 But coming from the Gateway it doesn't. I get HTTP/2.0 503 everytime (upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: remote reset).

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: Gateway
metadata:
name: my-gateway
namespace: default
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
  - hosts:
    - myhost.localhost
    port:
      name: http
      number: 80
      protocol: HTTP
    tls:
      httpsRedirect: true
  - hosts:
    - myhost.localhost
    port:
      name: https
      number: 443
      protocol: HTTPS
    tls:
      credentialName: myhost-tls
      mode: SIMPLE
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: my-api-gateway
  namespace: default
spec:
  gateways:
  - my-gateway
  hosts:
  - '*'
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /dev/my/
    rewrite:
      uri: /
    route:
    - destination:
        host: my-api
        port:
          number: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-api
  namespace: default
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http2
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: my-api
  type: ClusterIP
```

This is my log from istio-ingressgateway:

```
[2022-05-23T19:38:58.026Z] "GET /dev/my/version HTTP/2" 503 URX via_upstream - "-" 0 85 73 73 "10.244.5.0" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.64 Safari/537.36 Edg/101.0.1210.47" "3c497583-62cc-4b35-b64d-7410ad24e8bb" "myhost.localhost" "10.244.5.35:80" outbound|80||my-api.default.svc.cluster.local 10.244.3.160:37342 10.244.3.160:8443 10.244.5.0:14107 myhost.localhost -
```

And this is from envoy-proxy in my-api pod sidecar:

```
[2022-05-23T19:43:57.195Z] "GET /dev/my/version HTTP/2" 503 UR upstream_reset_before_response_started{remote_reset} - "-" 0 85 1 - "10.244.3.1" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.64 Safari/537.36 Edg/101.0.1210.47" "9d8d54b7-0683-42b4-bcd3-2725aa31c09e" "myhost.localhost" "10.244.5.35:80" inbound|80|| 127.0.0.6:50447 10.244.5.35:80 10.244.3.1:0 outbound_.80_._.my-api.default.svc.cluster.local default
```

Currently using istio 1.13.4